# Object of type Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager is not callable

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-9, laravel-api, php-jwt

As part of API development, I use Laravel 9 and use "php-open-source-saver/jwt-auth" package for authentication without tokens. The API works fine, but I get an error when I add the following line to the controller

```
$this->middleware('auth:api', ['except' => ['login','register']);
```

> Object of type Illuminate/Auth/AuthManager is not callable

API Response With Trace

```
{
  "message": "Object of type Illuminate\\Auth\\AuthManager is not callable",
  "exception": "Error",
  "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\shmooz\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
  "line": 181,
  "trace": [
    {
      "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\shmooz\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings.php",
      "line": 50,
      "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\shmooz\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
      "line": 180,
      "function": "handle",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\shmooz\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\ThrottleRequests.php",
      "line": 126,
      "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\shmooz\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\ThrottleRequests.php",
      "line": 102,
      "function": "handleRequest",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\ThrottleRequests",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\shmooz\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\ThrottleRequests.php",
      "line": 54,
      "function": "handleRequestUsingNamedLimiter",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\ThrottleRequests",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\shmooz\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
      "line": 180,
      "function": "handle",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\ThrottleRequests",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\shmooz\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
      "line": 116,
      "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\shmooz\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php",
      "line": 799,
      "function": "then",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\shmooz\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php",
      "line": 776,
      "function": "runRouteWithinStack",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\shmooz\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php",
      "line": 740,
      "function": "runRoute",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\shmooz\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php",
      "line": 729,
      "function": "dispatchToRoute",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\shmooz\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php",
      "line": 190,
      "function": "dispatch",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\shmooz\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
      "line": 141,
      "function": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\shmooz\\vendor\\livewire\\livewire\\src\\DisableBrowserCache.php",
      "line": 19,
      "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\shmooz\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
      "line": 180,
      "function": "handle",
      "class": "Livewire\\DisableBrowserCache",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\shmooz\\vendor\\barryvdh\\laravel-debugbar\\src\\Middleware\\InjectDebugbar.php",
      "line": 66,
      "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\shmooz\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
      "line": 180,
      "function": "handle",
      "class": "Barryvdh\\Debugbar\\Middleware\\InjectDebugbar",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\shmooz\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest.php",
      "line": 21,
      "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\shmooz\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull.php",
      "line": 31,
      "function": "handle",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\shmooz\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
      "line": 180,
      "function": "handle",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\shmooz\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest.php",
      "line": 21,
      "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\shmooz\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TrimStrings.php",
      "line": 40,
      "function": "handle",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\shmooz\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
      "line": 180,
      "function": "handle",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TrimStrings",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\shmooz\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize.php",
      "line": 27,
      "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\shmooz\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
      "line": 180,
      "function": "handle",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\shmooz\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance.php",
      "line": 86,
      "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\shmooz\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
      "line": 180,
      "function": "handle",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\shmooz\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Http\\Middleware\\HandleCors.php",
      "line": 62,
      "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\shmooz\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
      "line": 180,
      "function": "handle",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Http\\Middleware\\HandleCors",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\shmooz\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Http\\Middleware\\TrustProxies.php",
      "line": 39,
      "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\shmooz\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
      "line": 180,
      "function": "handle",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Http\\Middleware\\TrustProxies",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\shmooz\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
      "line": 116,
      "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\shmooz\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php",
      "line": 165,
      "function": "then",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\shmooz\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php",
      "line": 134,
      "function": "sendRequestThroughRouter",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\shmooz\\public\\index.php",
      "line": 52,
      "function": "handle",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\shmooz\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\resources\\server.php",
      "line": 16,
      "function": "require_once"
    }
  ]
}
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Welcome to SO ... you added that where in your Controller, btw?

Comment: also a stacktrace would be helpful

Comment: i added in __construct function

Comment: @lagbox i added api response with trace

Comment: Did you figured out, where the error comes from?

Answer (score 1):

Check if the "$routeMiddleware" array in the Kernel.php is named right.
"$middlewareAliases" only works in Laravel 10

You should provide your Kernel.php for further inspection

Comment: I used some example code from GitHub, didnt realize it was Laravel 10, while my project is on Laravel 9, this was my error, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have currently run into (maybe) the same problem. Well, the error message from laravel `Object of type Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager is not callable` was the same.

I am using Laravel 10, and Laravel Passport for API Auth.

After some time of digging in the code, I came into the Routes and Middlewares, such as "auth", "auth:web" etc.  - that seems that the problem is trully relevant to yours, and so:

**Please, make sure, that your Kernel, in its property `$routeMiddleware` have a correct middleware for `auth`**

---

The "behind the answer":

I have made some changes about Authentication and am using custom middlewares, that are loaded using another custom libraries (splitting a code). The Kernel is separated by default from the rest of the libs and does not know about the Auth middleware.

There is a lib (in my case Passport, project in yours), which defines a routes that belong to an Auth middleware. That is just fine, but once it is about to be resolved, it uses the Kernel to check route middlewares, and, it must know that the 'auth.api' belongs to a middleware, and providing information to which one. Otherwise, it (the pipe) does not know how to get the middleware and uses the AuthManager instead, as the middleware.

The message about that the manager is not callable, is because it does not have a `handle` method, which middlewares (should) have, and tries to directly call the manager as it was a callback.

I hope this answer helps, although I hope much more that you have already found the solution of this problem.

Answer (score -1):

i also faced same issue, i removed this line

```
 public function __construct()
     {
        $this->middleware('auth:api', ['except' => ['login', 'refresh', 'logout']]);
     }
```

from controller and my api is working fine.

Comment: The question explicitly asks *why* that line causes the error. An answer saying to remove it is not helpful.